# Installation of objectaid in eclipse, no valid license was found

Tags: eclipse

I have followed the steps of this guide to install objectaid on eclipse GALILEO in ubuntu 10.10 :

http://www.objectaid.com/installation

But after the installation I get this message in console:

*ObjectAid Sequence Diagram is not available because no valid license was found.*

I suppose it's because is possible to buy also the non-free version.
I would try the evaluation version, how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you don't have an answer yet :

In order to evaluate the sequence diagram generator, you need to create an account with ObjectAid [**here**](https://www.objectaid.com/create-account). Using this accout, you can request an evaluation license which will unlock the feature.